# How to display values in list view

Tags: c#, listview, visual-studio-2005

I have code like this

```
 if(Data.ResourcePolicy == null)
                SubItems.Add(ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.m_nullString);
             else
                SubItems.Add(Data.ResourcePolicy.Name);

             if (Data.AgentVersion == null || Data.AgentVersion.Equals("0.0.0.0"))
                SubItems.Add(ResourcePolicySystemsControl.m_nullVersion);
             else
                SubItems.Add(Data.AgentVersion);
             SubItems.Add(Data.AgentState.ToString());
```

i need to display ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.m_nullString only if Data.ResourcePolicy == null, if (Data.ResourcePolicy == null) and Data.AgentVersion != null then i should display ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.unknown
How will i achieve this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this what you mean?

```
bool isNullVersion=(Data.AgentVersion ?? "0.0.0.0") == "0.0.0.0";
string policy= isNullVersion ? 
                           ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.m_nullString :
                           ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.unknown;
if (Data.ResourcePolicy !=null) policy=Data.ResourcePolicy.Name;
SubItems.Add(policy);
SubItems.Add(isNullVersion ? 
                            ResourcePolicySystemsControl.m_nullVersion :
                            Data.AgentVersion
            );
SubItems.Add(Data.AgentState.ToString());
```

Comment: there are two ways Data.ResourcePolicy will become null,If (Data.ResourcePolicy == null) && (Data.AgentVersion != null) that time only it should display ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.unknown)

Comment: It is more code, its doing more checks than your example. I've rewritten it to use the ?: operator if it helps.

Comment: getting Error 333 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' it would be helpful if you provide answer for this

Answer (score 1):

Extent the class of Data:

```
public class DataClass
{
    //....

    public string ResourcePolicyName
    {
        get { return ResourcePolicy != null ? ResourcePolicy.Name : ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.m_nullString; }
    }

    public string AgentVersionString
    {
        get
        {
            if (AgentVersion == null || AgentVersion.Equals("0.0.0.0"))
            {
                return ResourcePolicySystemsControl.m_nullVersion;
            }
            return AgentVersion;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here Data is not class for me , thats an instance of the interface that means i am getting value from interface